# How to paste controls into a UIScrollView in IB nicely?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

Everytime I layout all my controls in a UIView, and then forget they need to be inside a UIScrollView instead, I have to cut and paste them into the scrollview.

It works of course but it looses all of my layout and just dumps all of the controls on top of one another and I have to readjust their position all over again.

Is there any secret key combination or something that I'm missing that will retain their position or is this just the way IB is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest fix is this XCode menu command after selecting all the objects in the UIView:

**Editor > Embed In > Scroll View**

Then drag out the newly created UIScrollView out of the UIView in IB, then delete the now-empty UIView. Huzzah!

Also, a sticky note under your monitor that reads, "Are you sure you want to lay that out in a UIView?" might help. =)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like just what I was looking for.